# Obtener posición GPS con la máxima exatitud solo una sola vez en Android

Tags: java, android

Necesito obtener la coordenadas GPS solo una vez cuando el usuario pulsa un botón, teniendo en cuenta la exactitud de los datos, es decir consultar a menudo hasta tener la precisión, para así dar como buena la posición, tambien especificando un TIMEOUT, es decir si al X tiempo no se ha podido obtener una buena posición, parar la escucha.

Ahora mismo solo tengo como obtener una vez los datos del GPS, y veo que si voy pulsando el botón cada vez, los datos son más exactos.

Se podría dar como buena precisión el `accuracy` este menos de 20m

Comment: Así funciona, ya que para calcular la posición, se toma el último posicionamiento para acotar en qué zona estimar la posición. Una lectura "en frío" muy probablemente te dará una precisión muy baja (digamos que "le cuesta mucho estimar a qué satélite consultar"). La técnica que se usa en (*casi*) todas las aplicaciones es obtener muchas lecturas (20-30 segs por ejemplo) y calcular el promedio, descartando los valores que están más allá de 1-2 desviaciones estándar.

Answer (score 1):

Obtener la posicion GPS mas exacta se realiza mediante el proveedor de GPS. Lo que deseas es

> consultar a menudo hasta tener la precisión

Consultar varias veces en un lapso corto de tiempo puede traer por consecuencia un alto consumo de tu bateria, pero si lo deseas realizar, puedes obtener una muestra de lecturas y obtener la que tiene mayor precision, esto se realiza mediante el metodo **[getAccuracy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationProvider.html#getAccuracy())** del provider.

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
List<String> listaProviders = locManager.getAllProviders();     
LocationProvider provider = locManager.getProvider(listaProviders.get(0));
int precision = provider.getAccuracy();
boolean obtieneAltitud = provider.supportsAltitude();
int consumoRecursos = provider.getPowerRequirement();
```